# How to set-up Visual Studio inside Windows Docker Container on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, docker

Anyone know how i can run Visual Studio inside a windows docker container on a macOS? Apologies if this should be posted in superusers.

I would like to be able to run a C# application from Visual Studio inside a windows docker container on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6 Macbook Pro.

I am attempting to complete the exercise here:
[Developing Apps](https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/BuildingIntelligentApplications/blob/master/Lab%202.pdf)

The project type is not supported for Visual Studio 2017 Community (Mac) which i am guessing may be to do with absence of .NET which is why i am looking for a way to have a Visual Studio set up running on my Mac.

I have found a starter for ten here:

[Installing Windows Docker on Mac](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-start-a-windows-docker-container-on-my-mac-os-x/12953/3)

[Visual Studio Tools for Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker)

In essence seems to be (though i am not clear on the last few steps):

1) Install VirtualBox on OS X

2) Get Windows Server 2016 Tech Preview 5 ISO200

3) Create WS 2016 TP5 VM in virtualbox

4) Inside of that set up Docker and run Visual Studio

This all seems a little complicated and i am uncertain about step 4 in particular.

I would appreciate any helpful advice on how to achieve this set-up please.

Comment: As it says, you need to have Virtual Machine run on your Mac and inside the the Windows VM you need to run Docker for windows. You are trying to run Docker for Windows directly on Mac, which doesn't work. You need to have the VM Setup using Virtual Box and then execute Step #4

Comment: #2 Tech Preview Version, so it is a evaluation version

Comment: @TarunLalwani  Thank you